# Write excels to path with variable in R

Tags: r

I want to write excel files to a folder with the `writexl` package. I have a list of dfs and a list of names for these dfs. I want to create the excel files automatically with a for loop, something like:

```
for (i in 1:length(df_list)) {
 write_xlsx(df_list[[i]], 
             "C:/example_path/{name_list[[i]]}.xlsx",
             col_names = FALSE)
}
```

Is there an elegant way? The use of the `writexl` package is mandatory unfortunately.

Comment: `write_xlsx(df_list[[i]], paste0("C:/example_path/",name_list[[i]],".xlsx"))`

Comment: @maydin Thank you good Sir on teaching me some syntax :) Works perfectly